# it goes through but nothing is added on phpmyadmin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post

I have this PHP code , it gets data from an HTML file , when i click on submit it goes through with no problem but nothing is adding to the database! I never had this problem before. please help

```
     <?php
$SNHUID=$_POST['SNHUID'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$department=$_POST['department'];


@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db");
$select ="insert into t_users (SNHUID,FirstName,LastName,Department) values ('.$SNHUID.','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$department."')";

$sql=mysql_query($select);

print'<script type="text/javascript">';
print'alert("The data is inserted")';
print'</script>';
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_connect` is deprecated. What the `@` symbol supposed to do?

Comment: @i-- it is a dirty way of hiding errors

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding to prevent SQL injection and quoting issues.

Comment: Also, your concatenation is incorrect. Periods are not needed when placing simple variables inside a double-quoted string, unless you're breaking out of the double-quoted string. Which you're not. `'.$SNHUID.'`. But using prepared statements would remove this issue.

Comment: Mysql errors tend to be silent errors. No matter which API you're using for mysql queries, always check for errors when things don't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please replace this line.

I have added double quote before and after $SNHUID

```
$select ="insert into t_users (SNHUID,FirstName,LastName,Department) 
           values ('".$SNHUID."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$department."')";
```

Comment: Why should the OP "replace this line"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @bub I have added double quote before and after $SNHUID

Comment: this doesn't resolve the gaping SQL injection vulnerability, which would be the correct way to write the query.

Comment: @Adyson yes you are right. But I think the issue is not SQL injection. the user just ask data is not stored in the database so I have suggested this.

Comment: SQL injection is **always** an issue (as is anything security-related). You can kill two birds with one stone here by using parameterised queries. It'll remove any syntax errors and also protect the database, and OP will learn a good lesson about how to safely write SQL queries.

Comment: Yeah sure now onwards I remember this and suggest with remove gaping  SQL injection vulnerability issue.

Comment: @DastanBanae it may work but your database can still be hacked very easily by some malicious input. The data could be stolen, corrupted or even destroyed completely. Note the comments of myself and others regarding SQL Injection. See http://bobby-tables.com for an explanation of the risks you face and also some examples of how to write your queries safely in PHP. Note also that if you don't change to a newer MySQL library, your code will eventually stop working completely when you need to switch to PHP7.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your advice , I am very new in this, this is literally my first work with phpmyadmin .. and I am trying to design a small database for my company as the start

Comment: @DastanBanae no problem. Hopefully the advice will improve the security of this and other apps you write in future. It's a serious vulnerability which is frequently exploited by hackers (and don't assume you can trust the people within your company, (or the code being run on the company network) either!). P.S. As a technical/pedantic point, you're not really working with phpmyadmin here, you're working with MySQL. PHPMyAdmin is just another web app which interacts with a MySQL server. Your PHP code does not interact with phpmyadmin, it interacts with MySql. Always worth understanding the tools

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have your double/single-quotes wrong around `$SNHUID` variable in query. It probably leads to an error as MySQL does not understand literal `$SNHUID` string inside a query.
You can always check the error from your query using [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php//) after query.

As a side note, you should not directly pass arguments from user to a query as this may result in SQL-injection vulnerability. Use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: might be worth noting that prepared statements cannot be used with the `mysql_` library, which is one very good reason why it's deprecated. OP should consider switching to `mysqli` or `PDO` asap in order to allow them to use this feature, which will both protect the data from injection attacks and also greatly reduce the chance of the kind of syntax errors associated with string concatenation.